# Динамическое изменение адреса в адресной строке браузера.

Tags: веб-программирование, php, javascript

**Здравствуйте!**

Мне очень хотелось бы узнать, есть ли способы как-то динамически изменить текущий URL( точнее, GET запрос ) в адресной  строке браузера без перезагрузки страницы? Такое вообще возможно? Если нет, то что бы вы посоветовали на этот счет? Я вот, к примеру, пытался "проэмулировать" GET-запрос, заменив знак вопроса на знак решетки( # ), но по-моему это смотрится "дешево".

**Спасибо!**

Comment: а чем вам Ajax не подходит? просто не совсем понятно зачем вам это

Comment: Мне это необходимо для динамического( визуального ) обновления GET-запроса.

Comment: Алсо http://hashcode.ru/questions/164674/javascript-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-history-api.  Исчите в поиске господа, это не так тяжело, поверьте!

Answer (score 2):

Что значит c  решеткой "смотрится "дешево""? В твиттере этот же самый способ смотрится, имхо, очень даже "дорого". Более того поисковики [уже умеют](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=1125296) индексировать страницы с динамически обновляемым контентом, именно когда в урле находится "#!".

Comment: Спасибо за информацию =)

Answer (score 0):

URL можно поменять методом

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, url); // это работает в chrome
```

или

```
history.pushState(null, null, url); // а это в firefox
```

Comment: А для других браузеров....

Comment: ну так первая же [ссылка на библиотеку](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144071/), которая поддерживает все браузеры

Answer (score 0):

ну так первая же [ссылка на библиотеку](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144071/), которая поддерживает все браузеры

> Библиотека была протестирована в
> браузерах: IE 6+, FireFox 3+, Opera 11+,
> Opera Mobile 11+, Chrome 17+, Safari 5+